# How to write clock process triggering hold and reset pulses in VHDL?

Tags: switches, fpga, vhdl, timing, circuits

I am attempting to write VHDL for generating control signals to operate a switched integrator circuit. I'd like to create a 20us 50% duty cycle hold signal and a 5us reset signal when the hold signal is high. The process must be clocked at 100kHz. How can I edit this code to make a proper clock edge triggered process?

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Int_Control is
  port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    hold : out std_logic;
    reset : out std_logic;
);
end Int_Control;


architecture behavioral of Int_Control is

    signal clk : in std_logic;
    signal hold : out std_logic;
    signal reset : out std_logic;

begin
  
  process(clk, hold, reset)
    begin

      if rising_edge(clk) then
        hold <= '0';
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 5us;

      if falling_edge(clk) then
        wait for 5us;

      if rising_edge(clk) then
        wait for 5us;

      if falling_edge(clk) then
        wait for 5us;

      if rising_edge(clk) then
        hold <= '1';
        wait for 5us;

      if falling_edge(clk) then
        wait for 5us;

      if rising_edge(clk) then
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 5us;

      if falling_edge(clk) then
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 5us

      end if;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t put “wait 5 us” into synthesized code.
What you can do is set up a counter to count your 100khz (10ns) clocks.
So it’s simple enough to generate your HOLD signal which lasts 20ns.

But your reset is only 5us so you can’t generate that with only rising edges.
You could write something using negative and positive edge flops but it would be simpler just to use combinatorial logic for your reset signal.

Something like this perhaps:

[image]

Comment: Oops, already see an error - my combinatorial ANDs create an active high reset. You need to invert that - an exercise left to the reader!